# S3 bucket not displaying Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I created a S3 bucket and populated it by uploading few files in it. But I am not able to validate my use case to check the bucket size as the default metrics of total bucket size returns no data always.
Note: I am created the bucket in the AWS Console UI with default settings.

I waited for more than a week and even then I still see no data under Metrics tab and hence the s3 bucket is not listed in cloudwatch as well to configure the alarms.

Has any one faced the similar issue and help with how to resolve it?
Attaching screenshot of Metrics tab of my S3 bucket for reference,[image]

Comment: Are you using Amazon CloudWatch in the same region as the bucket? The S3 console shows buckets from all regions, but CloudWatch metrics will only show for the bucket in the same region where the bucket resides.

Comment: Yes I use cloud watch in the same region as S3 bucket. But I dont see my s3 bucket listed to create the metrics.

Comment: For me, the bucket is under: CloudWatch / Metrics (not 'Explorer') / S3 / Storage Metrics. It then lists my buckets and the metrics available for each of them. Or are you saying that you can see the metric names listed, but there are no actual metrics? Perhaps there is a time filter that is limiting the displayed data?

Comment: Unfortunately, its not working for the new buckets which I have created and the Metrics tab of the S3 bucket does not show any data. I tried creating the buckets with region us-east-1 and eu-central-1 and both does not show up

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you so much for the replies. In the Metrics tab of the S3 bucket the graphs shows empty data and In the cloudwatch the S3 bucket is not listed to create the metric for it. I had been waiting for more than a week and it shows no data always.

Comment: This is very strange, because metric names will only appear in CloudWatch if there is data available. That's why I was wondering whether time filter is impacting the display. Your screenshot is different to the above path that I followed to view my S3 metrics, so you might want to follow the clicks I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies!
The screenshot which i have attached is from the Metrics tab of the S3 bucket which shows no data.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I haven't faced issues with older created buckets. For new buckets which i have created and the metrics is not showing up (both in S3 bucket Metrics tab and also S3 bucket not listed on S3 Storage Metrics in Cloud watch) even after a wait of more than 7 days

Comment: Any chance this is a permissions issue with your logged-in user?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same. I am an admin of the AWS account and created a bucket with default settings. Also not getting metrics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The S3 storage metrics are visible under the Metrics Tab in the Bucket and CloudWatch after several hours after creating and bucket showing up at an unspecified time. Link for reference, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-monitoring.html